# Jquery generated input values not being posted on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, braintree

I'm using braintree to process payments for a website that I'm creating. The api requires that I generate a payment method nonce via javascript in order to process the payment. I'm able to generate the nonce on form submit and place it in the input field however, the value is not being posted.

The jquery:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#checkout').on("submit", function() {
      var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: "<?php echo $clientToken ?>"});
      client.tokenizeCard({
      number: $('#number').val(),
      cardholderName: $('#first_name').val() + ' ' + $('#last_name').val(),
      expirationMonth: $('#expiration_month').val(),   
      expirationYear: $('#expiration_year').val(),   
      cvv: $('#cvv').val(),
      }, function (err, nonce) {
      $("#checkout input[name=nonce]").val(nonce);
      $('#checkout input[name=random]').val('randomtext');
  });

      });
  });
```

The php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['last_name'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['phone_number'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['expiration_month'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['expiration_year'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['nonce'];
echo '<br/>';
echo $_POST['random'];
echo '<br/>';
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
'amount' => '113.00',
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $_POST['nonce'],
  'orderId' => 'order id',
  'customer' => array(
'firstName' => $_POST['first_name'],
'lastName' => $_POST['last_name'],
'phone' => $_POST['phone_number'],

  )

));

if ($result->success) {
print_r("success!: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction) {
print_r("Error processing transaction:");
print_r("\n  code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
print_r("\n  text: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseText);
} else {
print_r("Validation errors: \n");
print_r($result->errors->deepAll());
}
?>
```

The html:

```
<form id="checkout" name="checkout" action="checkout_result.php" method="post" style="width:20em;font-size:1.5em;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<table style="margin-top:0.5em;">
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">First Name:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;"data-braintree-name="first_name" name="first_name"     id="first_name" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Last Name:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;"data-braintree-name="last_name" name="last_name"    id="last_name" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Email Address:</td>
<td><input  style="font-size:0.75em;" name="email_address" id="email_address" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Phone Number:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Street Address:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="street_address" name="street_address"     id="street_address" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Apt #:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="extended_address" name="extended_address" id="extended_address" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Postal Code:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="postal_code" name="postal_code"     id="postal_code" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Card Number:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="number" name="number" id="number"     value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Expiration Month:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="expiration_month" name="expiration_month" id="expiration_month" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Expiration Year:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="expiration_year" name="expiration_year" id="expiration_year" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">CVV:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" data-braintree-name="cvv" name="cvv" id="cvv" value=""/>             </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Random:</td>
<td><input style="font-size:0.75em;" name="random" id="random" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="padding-left:0.75em;">Nonce:</td>
<td><input type="text" style="font-size:0.75em;" name="nonce" id="nonce" value=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div style="padding-top:0.25em;padding-bottom:0.25em;text-align:center;"><span><input     style="font-size:0.5em;" type="submit"
 id="submit" value="SUBMIT"/></span></div>
</div>

</form>
```

How do I get the nonce input field to post. The random text input field doesn't post either.

Comment: put it on [jsfiddle (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/t4p1grew/) my suggestion is to do something like this: `<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"nonce\" value=\"nonce()\">`. on js fiddle you can't add the php so submit button won't work, but you'll be able to mess with it and get the random number generator and jquery to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably with the fact, that `tokenizeCard` makes an asynchronous call to get the nonce. The flow of events is then like this:

```
submit form begins -> tokenizing begins -> submit form ends ->
(somewhere here the promise is resolved - the result comes back from the server)
-> tokenizing ends
```

What you can do is to add `return false` to the end of submit listener (conditions by the emptiness of nonce field) and then then call submit again (without getting the nonce from server again) from the client callback. It would look like this:

```js
$('#checkout').on("submit", function() {
  //I could be wrong in the condition below - it may be undefined
  if($("#checkout input[name=nonce]").val() === ''){ 
    var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: "<?php echo $clientToken ?>"});
    client.tokenizeCard({
      number: $('#number').val(),
      cardholderName: $('#first_name').val() + ' ' + $('#last_name').val(),
      expirationMonth: $('#expiration_month').val(),   
      expirationYear: $('#expiration_year').val(),   
      cvv: $('#cvv').val(),
    }, function (err, nonce) {
      $("#checkout input[name=nonce]").val(nonce);
      $('#checkout input[name=random]').val('randomtext');
      $('#checkout').submit();
    });
    return false; //stops form submitting
  } else {
    return true; //continues form submitting
  }
});
```

*Edit: This fiddle represents your problem exactly*

```js
$("#form").submit(function(){
    alert("submit invoked!");
    if($("#writeMe").val() === ''){
        writeValue();
        alert("submit not done - writeValue invoked");
    } else {
        alert("submit actually done");
    }
    return false;
}); 

function writeValue(){
    setTimeout(function() {
       alert("result's back -> gonna submit again");
       $("#writeMe").val("written");
       $("#form").submit(); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" readonly id="writeMe" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit me!" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could implement this without having to double click? I tried removing the return false but it submits without posting the values.

Comment: What do you mean by double click? `$('#checkout').submit();` should submit the form for you when the nonce come.

Comment: It does not submit. I assume the return false keeps the form from submitting. However, I've tried something similar and have found that $('checkout').submit(); doesnt work even when I strip it down and call it only from a button click. The only thing that works is $('#submit').trigger('click'). The values do not post , though.

Comment: Is value put inside nonce field? Is it possible, that you've made some spelling mistake inside submit invocation (like in your comment you missed `#` char before `checkout` id. This fiddle shows that `$("#form").submit()` works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/bandrzejczak/9mzbkx84/

Comment: The code above works. Thank you. However, .submit() doesn't work. I've instead switched it with $('submit').trigger('click');